# How to remove channels menu from channel navigation

Tags: youtube

I can't find how to remove the Channels (featured channels tab in channel navigation). I don't have other channels to feature on my channel. 
I can't find anything related in YouTube Help or anywhere else in the internet. The funny thing is that YouTube's help, displays the same image without the Channels Tab, but I have been looping around every corner in YT and can't find any setting for this.

How can I do this?

[image]

ScreenShot from YT Help pages...

[image]

Comment: anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: This is still unknown to me. Anyone ?

Comment: You might have noticed, like I have, even custom tabs right? These are brand pages that work with their Google business rep - they are advertising accounts.

Answer (score 1):

1. On your channel page, click the Customize Channel button
2. Click Community
3. On the right part, there is a small channel list
4. Click on the edit (pencil) button on the channel you want to remove
5. Click Delete

Comment: I don't think it answers the question